# Here android sdk sample code showing blank screen

Tags: android, here-api

I have downloaded here android sdk 90 day eval.
Tried to run the basic map sample application, but getting blank in the map frame.
I am able to see hello world text.
Seperately i also have here maps app running on my mobile, which runs without any problem.
I have my internet connection and location settings on.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the app_id/app_code and lisence key(if you are using the premium edition) in your maifest file, as mentioned here :

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/credentials.html

Otherwise try debugging your app by adding a break point in the mapFragment.init() method , for example using the code on following link , try putting a break point on the line

```
 (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE)
```

to check if there is any error.

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/app-simple.html